# What's the difference between BIGINT and INT8? (postgres)

Tags: postgresql

I'm using a service called Supabase and I created a table:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table ( 
    "id" BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    "title" Text COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
    "message" Text COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default");
```

However, this turns into an int8 type. Is that smaller than bigint?

Comment: No. `int8` is an alias for `bigint`. You can check for yourself - `CREATE TABLE foo(bar int8);`, then `\d foo` in psql. You'll see that column bar has type bigint.

Comment: See for your self [Integers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-INT)

Comment: I wonder what was in the mind of the person who came up with idea of reusing 8bit type name for 8byte type :O

Answer (score 18):

`BIGINT` is just an alias for `INT8` in PostgreSQL. Try this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t (
  c1 bigint,
  c2 int8
);

SELECT a.attname, t.typname
FROM pg_class AS c 
JOIN pg_attribute AS a ON a.attrelid = c.oid
JOIN pg_type AS t ON a.atttypid = t.oid
WHERE c.relname = 't'
AND a.attname IN ('c1', 'c2')
ORDER BY 1;
```

You'll get:

```
|attname|typname|
|-------|-------|
|c1     |int8   |
|c2     |int8   |
```

There's no stored type name `bigint` in `pg_type`:

```sql
SELECT * FROM pg_type WHERE typname IN ('int8', 'bigint');
```

This only returns:

```
|typname|
|-------|
|int8   |
```